# body-parser, Unexpected token u in JSON at position

Tags: node.js, json, express, body-parser

I am using body-parser to get at the body of a POST request. My `index.js` file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body);
    res.send("test");
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});



app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!');
});
```

When I boot up my docker, I get the listening message as expected.

When I run the command:

```
curl -d {"user":"Someone"} -H "Content-Type: application/json" --url http://localhost:8080
```

I get the error:

```
Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I'm confused because I don't directly call json.parse anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is in the request. Body should be a string:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message": "foo"}' http://localhost:8080/messages`

Comment: since I'm doing this in command line, I just tried `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \ --request POST \ --data '{"user":"Someone"}' \ http://localhost:8080/` but I get, several errors

Comment: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: --request curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST curl: (6) Could not resolve host: --data curl: (3) Port number ended with '"' curl: (1) Protocol " http" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: Try:  `curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"user":"Someone"}' http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

You need 
`curl -d "{"user":"Someone"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --url http://localhost:8080;` sometimes Curl doesn't parses single quotes.